# WildFly error during deployment

Tags: java, lambda, wildfly, dynatrace

When trying to deploy an application to a WildFly 8.2. I am getting the following error and my application is not starting at all. The JDK version is 1.8.0_51.

016-02-06 09

```
:38:49 [e8c32865] info    [native] Instrumentation channel connected successfully
2016-02-06 09:38:50 [e8c32865] warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java 7 classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/lang/CharSequence)
2016-02-06 09:38:50 [e8c32865] warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java 7 classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement)
2016-02-06 09:38:53 [e8c32865] warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java 7 classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/util/Comparator)
2016-02-06 09:39:04 [e8c32865] info    [native] Agent classes defined successfully
2016-02-06 09:39:05 [e8c32865] warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java 7 classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/util/Map$Entry)
2016-02-06 09:39:06 [e8c32865] warning [native] Error during parsing of java bytecode: Java 7 classes with "invokedynamic" are not supported, skipping class transformation (class java/util/Arrays)
```

How can we solve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE :**

Issue fixed when we disabled 'dynatrace' in the server. 
But, need to solve this issue without disabling the dynatrace.

Comment: Seems to be a known bug, but red hat won't let us see the solution. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1420783

Comment: Generally, if you wish to use software that parses bytecode with Java 8, you need an up to date version that can handle Java 8’s bytecode. So the solution obviously has something to do with updating either, the entire product or the component responsible for bytecode processing.

Answer (score 2):

This is problem with dynatrace not supporting java 8 bytecode properly.
You can either

- disable dynatrace
- try to configure dynatrace to not process java.lang classes
- ignore the messages
- contact dynatrace about possible upgrade or configuration option to address this

Comment: Just want to clarify. The latest version of Dynatrace does support Java 8 Bytecode. The question is on which Dynatrace version you are on